# Some bars are missing from the plotly dash plot randomly

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am creating a dashboard using Plotly Dash which contains plots with a bar and a line graph on the common x axis. The code is working fine when I run it, however when I am selecting different options from the dropdown to change the graph, some bars go missing from the plot randomly for some options.
Here is an example that’s working perfectly fine.[perfectly fine image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSFFo.png)

And here is an example where a bar goes missing from the plot when i select a different option from dropdown.

[image with missing bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8juBH.png)

I am not sure what’s wrong. I have checked if the data is missing for the missing bar but it’s there and when I am hovering over the missing bar area in the plot, it is also showing me the value there but not the bar. For reference, here is my code…

```
trace1  = go.Scatter(
    mode='lines+markers+text',
    x = df1['Date'],
    y = df1['AVG'],
    name="Avg time(mins)",
    text=df1['AVG'],
    textposition='bottom right',
    textfont_color='black',
    marker_color='blue',
    opacity=1
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x = df1['Date'],
    y = df1['Id_Count'],
    name="Count",
    ids=df1['Id_Count'],
    text=df1['Id_Count'],
    textposition='inside',
    insidetextfont_color='#45FC03',
    hoverinfo='x+y',
    yaxis='y2',
    marker_color ='#180702',
    marker_line_width=1.5,
    marker_line_color='black',
    opacity=0.72
)
data1 = [trace1, trace2]

layout1 = go.Layout(
title_text='Day wise stats',
title_font_color='#45FC03',
width=1300,
height=400,
yaxis=dict(
    side = 'right'
),
yaxis2=dict(
    overlaying='y',
    anchor='y3',
    )
)

fig1 = go.Figure(data=data1, layout=layout1)
fig1.update_layout(template='plotly_dark',
plot_bgcolor='#F0E199', paper_bgcolor='#282522',  margin_l=50, margin_t=80, margin_b=60)
fig1.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
fig1.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
```

Please, any help would be appreciated for a solution to this problem.

Comment: there's nothing to show how you are filtering.  I suspect that bars go missing because associated value in filtered dataframe is NaN.  this is not random, but functioning based of data / how filtering is done

Answer (score 0):

- contents of bars is based on data in dataframe
- below code shows bar disappears if underlying dataframe has **NaN** as value

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":pd.date_range("28-sep-2021", freq="D", periods=7), "AVG":np.round(np.random.uniform(2,5,7),2), "Id_Count":np.random.randint(2000,3000,7)})

def graph(df1):
    trace1  = go.Scatter(
        mode='lines+markers+text',
        x = df1['Date'],
        y = df1['AVG'],
        name="Avg time(mins)",
        text=df1['AVG'],
        textposition='bottom right',
        textfont_color='black',
        marker_color='blue',
        opacity=1
    )
    trace2 = go.Bar(
        x = df1['Date'],
        y = df1['Id_Count'],
        name="Count",
        ids=df1['Id_Count'],
        text=df1['Id_Count'],
        textposition='inside',
        insidetextfont_color='#45FC03',
        hoverinfo='x+y',
        yaxis='y2',
        marker_color ='#180702',
        marker_line_width=1.5,
        marker_line_color='black',
        opacity=0.72
    )
    data1 = [trace1, trace2]

    layout1 = go.Layout(
    title_text='Day wise stats',
    title_font_color='#45FC03',
    width=800,
    height=400,
    yaxis=dict(
        side = 'right'
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        overlaying='y',
        anchor='y3',
        )
    )

    fig1 = go.Figure(data=data1, layout=layout1)
    fig1.update_layout(template='plotly_dark',
    plot_bgcolor='#F0E199', paper_bgcolor='#282522',  margin_l=50, margin_t=80, margin_b=60)
    fig1.update_xaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    fig1.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, zeroline=False)
    return fig1

graph(df1).show()

df1.loc[df1.sample(1).index, "Id_Count"] = np.nan
graph(df1).show()
```